# YouTube Live Streaming API Broadcast Start Date Timezone Not Working

Tags: timezone, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using youtube live streaming api to setup my live events. When I set date to **scheduledStartTime** and save the event, it stores date time but it ignores **Timezone**.

No matter what timezone value I set, I always end up with **(GMT-7)**. Here is an example of what I set **2015-09-10T21:00:00.0000000+04:00** I'd end up with **(GMT+4)**

Does anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of the API call, and also an example or screenshot of how you're retrieving the result.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [YouTube Live Streaming API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts), the format for `scheduledStartTime` must be in ISO 8601 format:

> `datetime`
>
> The date and time that the broadcast is scheduled to start.
>   The value is specified in [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

You didn't list a specific platform, but my working date format string on iOS is as follows:

```
YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

Comment: Sorry, my platform is C# and date format string is yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz  ISO 8601